# Only 2 resolutions in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

How Can use only two designs in Bootstrap 4?

I meam. I want to use one design for LG and MD screens and another one for SM and XS.

How Can hide anothers designs and block item positions when I resize the screen?

Best regards

Comment: I need explain better?

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting the width variables to be identical for the two pairs: LG and MD and for SM and XS will work.

Comment: But when I know when navbar collapse?

Comment: Navbar-collapse is set to display:none is a certain screen mode. It isn’t affected.